# Silent authentification with cas oidc (prompt=none)

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, thymeleaf, openid-connect, cas

I have a cas server work with oidc; I want to login without approve page. So I hava get the url like this

https://xxx:9443/cas/oidc/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/callback?client_name=OidcClient&client_id=biitt&scope=openid&prompt=none;

my cas server version is 5.3 and only config the prompt=none will got error, if config the prompt=consent/login it will be ok; I also have try config the display=none, but it doesnt work. Any infomation will be greatful.

I have try to read the source code and found if config the prompt=none, it will call the interface path = {"/oauth2.0/callbackAuthorize"} and then do resolve method, then the resolve method will construct the mav with the original url, so it always return the thymeleaf template is not exsit.

[resolve method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZRq8.png)

The error msg is :

The error info is : 2022-07-26 15:03:11,859 ERROR [org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine] - <[THYMELEAF][https-openssl-nio-9443-exec-1] Exception processing template "https://biitt-cas.com:9443/cas/oidc[...]lient_name=OidcClient&client_id=biitt&scope=openid%20profile%20email&prompt=none": Error resolving template [https://biitt-cas.com:9443/cas/oidc/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/callback?client_name=OidcClient&client_id=biitt&scope=openid%20profile%20email&prompt=none], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [https://biitt-cas.com:9443/cas/oidc/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/callback?client_name=OidcClient&client_id=biitt&scope=openid%20profile%20email&prompt=none], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE] at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE] at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE] at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE] at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:360) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE] at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:192) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE] at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[servlet-api.jar:?] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE] at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[servlet-api.jar:?] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apereo.cas.web.support.AuthenticationCredentialsThreadLocalBinderClearingFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationCredentialsThreadLocalBinderClearingFilter.java:30) ~[cas-server-core-web-api-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apereo.cas.security.RequestParameterPolicyEnforcementFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterPolicyEnforcementFilter.java:261) ~[cas-server-security-filter-2.0.10.4.jar:2.0.10.4] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apereo.cas.security.ResponseHeadersEnforcementFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeadersEnforcementFilter.java:240) ~[cas-server-security-filter-2.0.10.4.jar:2.0.10.4] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apereo.cas.security.AddResponseHeadersFilter.doFilter(AddResponseHeadersFilter.java:94) ~[cas-server-security-filter-2.0.10.4.jar:2.0.10.4] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.18.RELEASE.jar:1.5.18.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apereo.cas.logging.web.ThreadContextMDCServletFilter.doFilter(ThreadContextMDCServletFilter.java:91) ~[cas-server-core-logging-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.18.RELEASE.jar:1.5.18.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.5.18.RELEASE.jar:1.5.18.RELEASE] at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66) ~[spring-boot-1.5.18.RELEASE.jar:1.5.18.RELEASE] at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105) ~[spring-boot-1.5.18.RELEASE.jar:1.5.18.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE] at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123) ~[spring-boot-1.5.18.RELEASE.jar:1.5.18.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apereo.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:66) ~[inspektr-common-1.8.4.GA.jar:1.8.4.GA] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71) ~[log4j-web-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.7] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.7] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_281] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_281] at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.7] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_281]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more context for this issue?
If you haven't ever logged into that server from a device, you should not be able to do a silent log on. [Specification of Implementation](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Consent:%7E:text=%C2%A0TOC-,3.1.2.3.%C2%A0%20Authorization%20Server%20Authenticates%20End%2DUser,-If%20the%20request)
Essentially prompt applies to a user that has already been authenticated.

If the user has been authenticated this will most likely be related to session cookie settings.

Comment: thanks for your reply first , I have to try the cas 6.3 by use "bypassApprovalPrompt": true; then I found that I was misunderstood about the prompt=none; my goal just to skip the approval page, not the login page.

Comment: By use 6.3 , I got the prompt=none means once you have logged into from the device, you will no longger need to log in again. just like you said. 

But the cas 6.3 will return the error code : require-login, its clear to undertand; the cas 5.3 will give me the exception. I still dont know why.

BTW, For 5.3, is there some way can skip the approval page just like use the "bypassApprovalPrompt": true in 6.3 version.